# How do I show a jQuery validation error on a textbox based on a hidden input field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dropdown list that I'm converting over to a custom modal dialog. The conversion requires that we have a text field that shows the name of the item selected and a hidden field that holds the ID of the item selected:

```
<input id="template" type="text" class="text inactive" value="Select a template...">
<span class="button">Select...</span>

<input id="templateid" type="hidden" class="required" name="template" title="You must select a template.">
```

When the user clicks on the **Select...** button, a modal dialog pops up, allowing the user to pick a template. After the user is done selecting a template, the `template` text box is set with the name of the template, and the `templateid` hidden field is set with the ID of the template:

```
$('#templateDialog .okButton').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).find('li.selected');
    var name = item.find('.name').text();
    var id = item.find('.id').text();
    
    $('#template').val(name);
    $('#templateid').val(id);
    $('#templateDialog').dialog('close');
});
```

All this is working fine. The issue I'm running into now is validation, using **jQuery Validation**. Because the hidden input has the `required` class, when I try to submit the form without picking a template, the error message is displayed properly. However, the `template` text box is not styled. I would like it to get the `invalid` class.

**My question is**, how do I configure jQuery so that, if the `templateid` hidden field is invalid, the `template` text box is invalid as well, and if it's valid, the text box is valid as well?

**Update:** here's a picture:

[image]

See how the **Confirm password** text box has a red outline, but the **Template** text box does not? I'd like for it to be red too.

Comment: Can you post Jquery validation code?

Comment: It's just `$('form').validate();`. I'm using jQuery metadata to handle the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery validation plugin provides two handlers to customize the way the erroneous fields are changed visually: `highlight` and `unhighlight`.

```
$(".selector").validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

        if ([case of the input]) {
        // check here the case of you file input and add the errorClass to the file input or its container
        }
        else {
         // don't forget to apply the class to element in the other cases as defining this handler will remove the default behavior
            $(element).removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
        }
     }
});
```

Do the contrary with unhighlight handler.

Hope this helps,
d.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function on Invalid event.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   invalidHandler: function(form) {
    // do other stuff for a invalidvalid form

   }
})
```

see [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#code)